# Mobile Google Chrome Not Resizing Responsive Website

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-webdesign

I am new to designing responsive websites which are done in pure PHP and CSS, and I am not using any CMS like wordpress. I am using `@media screen` and `(max-width:....)` for the responsive design only (no Javascript nor anything like it).

My question is when I test the responsive website in mobile google chrome that website does not resize but renders as if it was on a pc screen. If I use the desktop Google Chrome browser and resize the window it works perfectly. **Do I need to tell mobile Chrome to resize within my website for it to render the website to that screen size or is that how mobile Chrome works now?**

Comment: What meta viewport tag are you setting?

Comment: If you are using developer tools and clicked the little phone icon to test your mobile site, *you will need to refresh the webpage*. You can use the icon to the left of the phone icon or just right-click the page area and do a refresh from there.

Comment: This question belongs on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Guys on stack overflow said that this same question belongs on webmasters. I am using Dreamweaver and it renders correctly on the mobile preview.

Comment: I am assuming my problem is the viewport tag, I did some research and that was my problem. Thanks @w3d

Comment: What meta viewport tag are you setting? – w3d I did some research and that was my problem. Thanks @w3d – Paddy

Comment: @Paddy I find it odd that they would say that, it seems more likely they would close it as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156510/responsive-website-zoomed-out-to-full-width-on-mobile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not add any viewports, so I did some research and added this view port `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

This sorted my problem. Thanks guys for the help.